# Gnucash and macports conflicting libgio-2.0.0.dylib

Tags: macos, macports, dynamic-library

I have macports 2.5.2 already installed.
I have then installed Gnucash 3.2 dmg from gnucash.org.
When I run gnucash, I have the error:

> objc[93365]: Class GNotificationCenterDelegate is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Gnucash.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libgio-2.0.0.dylib
>   (0x10c333670) and /opt/local/lib/libgio-2.0.0.dylib (0x117a41620). One
>   of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>   Segmentation fault:
>   11

/opt/local/lib/libgio-2.0.0.dylib belongs to glib2 macports package.

**If I rename /opt/local/lib/libgio-2.0.0.dylib, gnucash works fine**. But this can't be a solution.

I've also tried to set DYLB_LIBRARY_PATH to

> /Applications/Gnucash.app/Contents/Resources/lib

But this way I have the error

> Segmentation fault: 11

Is there a way to run gnucash while macports installed ?

Comment: Install gnucash from macports should work. Where are you setting environment variables? I would also say Gnucash.app has not set itself up correctly

Comment: Macports gnucash doesn't build on my Mac. I've opened ticket #56675. I've used export DYLIB_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/Gnucash.app/Contents/Resources/lib";/Applications/Gnucash.app/Contents/MacOS/Gnucash.

Comment: variables in ~./bash* do not affecrt lainching from Finder etc

Comment: The macports bufg needs the log as the text says - also try with a plain command line

Comment: That's what I'm doing. I have a script that exports DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and then runs `/Applications/Gnucash.app/Contents/MacOS/Gnucash`. I don't launch anything from the lanchpad, the finder...Furthermore `otool -L /Applications/Gnucash.app/Contents/MacOS/Gnucash` doesn't show any /opt reference. And env command doesn't show any /opt/local/lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved now.
I have completely uninstalled macports, removed /opt/local directory, and then reinstalled macports.
I tried to install macports gnucash, but it is still impossible.
But the dmg gnucash works now perfectly.
I have no explanation.